# Can I ask "how to develop this windows-like visual control"?

Tags: support, scope

I would like to ask if it is prohibited or not to ask Stack Overflow questions like this one:

> There exists the X visual control in Windows 8.  How can I create such
>   a control in my app using visual studio?

For example I am thinking of uploading a picture of a specific Windows 8 native control which I want to add to my application and I do not know if Visual studio provides this control.

Comment: I don't know enough about the subject to tell whether that is on-topic but it looks like to be a "give me the code" question. If you've searched thoroughly and there really is nothing that indicates whether it's possible then it might be okay but don't be surprised if you get downvotes if you word it like this. You should be very clear about what you have done to find out for yourself. i.e. more than "I searched on Google"

Comment: Possibly, you've just got an amazing answer though. If you follow the suggestions there you'll be more than fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best questions on Stack Overflow are about a real, actual problem that you're facing, one where you've clearly described the problem, as well as what you've tried so far, and why you're trying to do what you're trying to do.

### **Show research so we don't repeat ourselves:**

It's not that your question is off-topic, but rather that it shows no research effort on your part. While this might seem like we're asking a lot, as someone who has answered a lot of questions, I can tell you that it's quite frustrating when you've explained to someone, in painstaking clarity and detail, how to accomplish something, only to have an indignant asker exclaim:

> no! i tried that alredy and it dont work!

That doesn't help you, and it doesn't help me. It surely doesn't help future visitors who could benefit from the Q&A.

So when we ask you to show your research, it's not necessarily that we think you're lazy, it's that we don't want to waste time regurgitating stuff you've already done.

### **Try to solve the problem yourself first, so you understand the problem better:**

Additionally, there are likely already resources on the Internet that explain how to create a control using Visual Studio. This would be a good place for you to start, actually. After trying out a tutorial and getting stuck, you'd then have a better understanding of your problem, which not only means you can describe it better, but also that you'll have a better chance of *actually understanding what the answerers are saying to you.*

One of the problems that I see with people who did no prior research is that they typically need to ask far more follow up questions in the comments. This is a turnoff to people who like helping other people, it wears them out, and it generally leads to questions and answers that might not be as helpful to others with the same problem.

### **Even if you can't give answers, you can give back by asking great questions:**

Consider this: If you can't answer questions yet, because you're too busy or because you're really new to the programming field, the way you can give back to the community is by asking well-researched questions. Answers can't exist without good questions.

*Consider that for every real problem that you personally face, that's well articulated and describes your problem, what you've tried, and why, hundreds and thousands of other people with the same problem will potentially benefit from your post! If you can write questions that do that,* ***then you're awesome!*** *I don't care how new you are to programming!* :)

Comment: I find it difficult to search the internet to find how to reproduce a control for which I only know.. its image. Nevertheless, I insisted googling it more than before and I found its name.. Thanks for providing me a motivation to insist searching for it, rather than uploading a control image and asking what's its name!